# Facebook Marketing API Insights

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

We are trying to fetch some data from the Marketing API through the Ad Account Insights.

We have found most of the fields we need, but we can't find a field that corresponds to the "3-Seconds Video Views" property that is available in the web-interface.

The following fields are available:

- video_10_sec_watched_actions
- video_15_sec_watched_actions
- video_30_sec_watched_actions

But the 3 second one is missing here. Does anyone know if there is a way to get this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you request the field `actions` you can look for the field called `video_view`. This is any video view for at least 3 seconds.

You can see all of the actions available here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ads-action-stats/